# Help with game development. Render loop?

Tags: game-engine, game-loop

I'm working on a simple game, this is my first game project.

Most of the samples I find have a Render Loop where all the game logic is made too and I just don't like this.
Let's say I have a ball with X=0, and a wall in X=10 and in a slow machine, the first loop places the ball in X=7 and in a second loop, it places the ball in X=14. It would just crash the game!

Is this "render loop" the right way to make games? Should I write code to check for things like this in every frame? Example, new frame X=14, last frame have X=7, so I should check if there's anything from X=7 to X=14??

I was thinking that I should have a separated thread for the game logic and in the render loop, I should just "take a snapshot" of the current game logic and display that, no?

How do you guys, experienced game developers work around this?

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As another answer stated, the problem you're seeing is called "tunneling"  It's the "bullet through paper" problem, the bullet is moving fast, the paper is thin, how do you know that a collision happened?

It's easy if your world boundaries are simple.  E.g. in Tetris, the blocks are only allowed to move left and right until they hit the sides, and it's easy to test if the bottom-most coordinate is hitting the "ground."  These tests are simple because you can do one axis at a time, and collisions against the sides means something different than collisions against the bottom of the pit.  If you have a rectangular room, just "stop" the moving object if its movement has put it outside the room by clamping its coordinates.  I.e. if the room width is from -3 to +3, and your object has an X of 5, just change it to 3 and you're done.

If you want to handle more complicated worlds, it's a bit trickier.  You'll want to read up on "swept" geometry collision.  Basically, if you have a circle, you need to do collision tests with a capsule instead, the shape that would be made by "sweeping" the circle from its start point to its end point.  It'll be like a rectangle with semicircles on either end.  The math is surprisingly straight forward (IMHO), but it can be tricky to get it right and to truly understand what's going on.  It's worth it though!

**Edit:** On the thread issue- no need to complicate things.  One thread is fine.  Skipping update frames can get messy too, and is pretty advanced since you actually need to figure out "the future" and then do interpolation of all interesting values up to that point.  I don't call it the "render" loop, myself, as the render loop is just one part of the process.

```
def GameLoop():
   while True:
      ReadInputs()
      FigureOutWhatStuffDoes()
      DrawItAll()
```

**Edit 2:** This seems like an interesting discussion: http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=482397

Answer (score 3):

If you create a separate thread for this you also create a lot of complexity that you might not want to deal with. It's easy to handle with one thread and one loop.

Basically what you want to do is have a loop that does both logic and rendering, but not necessarily in every iteration. See this pseudo-code:

```
while(true) {
   oldTime = currentTime;
   currentTime = systemTime();
   timeStep = currentTime - oldTime;

   // Only do logic x times / second
   if( currentTime > lastLogicTime + logicRefreshTime ){
      doGameLogic( currentTime - lastLogicTime );
      lastLogicTime = currentTime;
   }

   // Extrapolate all movements using timeStep
   renderGraphics( timeStep );

   wait( screenRefreshTime );
}

void doGameLogic( timeStep ) {
   // Update all objects
   for each( gameObject obj )
     obj.move( timeStep );
}
```

Let all solid movable objects inherit the class SolidObject. When you call `SolidObject.move(timeStep)` that method checks to see how far the object can be moved within the given `timeStep`. If there is a wall before this point then the object should stop, bounce and change direction, die or whatever you like.

---

**Edit:**

If two objects move you might want to check **if** and **where** they collide. Lots of games don't do this very well, but here's how you do it:

First calculate the line of movement between the `oldTime` and the `currentTime` for every object that moves. Then compare the lines to see if two lines intersect. Note, you need to take the objects' size into account. The intersection point is where the objects collide. Using this method you can accurately detect collisions of moving objects.

Comment: Hmmm shouldn't you check the game logic then render? I think rendering is the last thing you should do since you need all your data to be valid before actually displaying it on screen.

Comment: @Cristina: yeah, you should probably do that. You can also choose to interpolate instead of extrapolate if correctness is more important than responsiveness.

Comment: The reason why a lot of games don't do it well because the "then compare the lines to see if two lines intersect" is not trivial to solve if the geometry gets complex.  Naively comparing each pair of lines will kill your frame time pretty quick.  Plus- even if the lines intersect you've still got a lot of work to figure out if the objects should actually collide; the collision shouldn't happen if the intersection is at the "start" of one object's movement and at the "end" of the other's.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: you are so right. One way to simplify the object collision test is to use simpler collision shapes than the actual shapes of the objects. Old 2D games usually had invisible collision boxes. For 3D games you can use cylinders or even spheres with good results - that's only the line + the radius of the sphere. I'm not saying it's trivial, of course.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to have a separate **update-thread** and a **drawing-thread**, but it isn't easy! Usually you'll need to do a lot of *mutex* checking to prevent multithreaded access to the same variables so this isn't really viable (plus you don't want to handle with half-updated states). For a correct implementation you indeed need to have some form of snapshot of the last render state. If you don't mind the difficulty involved, there is a good implementation that van be found here:

http://blog.slapware.eu/game-engine/programming/multithreaded-renderloop-part1/

http://blog.slapware.eu/game-engine/programming/multithreaded-renderloop-part2/

Don't let naysayers discourage you. It is possible, it is viable and efficient. The only downside is that it is very difficult to implement and therefore probably not worth your time (unless you have a very CPU-heavy game).

Answer (score 2):

Don't thread it -- you'll cause more problems than you'll solve.  You **can** thread things and separate logic updates and rendering, but it's tricky to get right and large portions of game loops are inherently single-threaded.

Instead, look into advancing your game loop using a delta time to scale things so that the logic update is largely independent of the machine's ability to chomp through the frames.

In simplified terms, if you use a delta to scale things, regardless of how long it takes to get through a frame, a ball moving from one side of a room to another will take the same amount of time to do it on a really fast PC and a slow one.

E.g. If a ball moves 10 units in one second and you can determine that 0.1 seconds has passed since the last update (use the high performance timer or whatever is available to you), you simply scale the movement by 0.1 and the ball moves 1 unit.

E.g.

```
private const float BallSpeedInMetresPerSecond = 10;

public void Update(float deltaTimeInSeconds)
{
    float adjustedSpeed = deltaTimeInSeconds * BallSpeedInMetresPerSecond;
    // set ball's speed / move it etc. using adjusted speed
}
```

This won't entirely solve your problem (if something is *really* fast, it's going to get stuck in walls regardless!), but it is a simple and effective way to keep things predictable and consistent until you get into more complicated problems.

If you get that working and then want to solve a more complicated problem, as dash-tom-bang said, look into swept collision detection.

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking that I should have a
>   separated thread for the game logic
>   and in the render loop, I should just
>   "take a snapshot" of the current game
>   logic and display that, no?

There is no way that is simple, safe, and fast to take a snapshot of a massive lump of game state. You can double-buffer it, which is probably the next best thing. But it doesn't fix the problem anyway, so no, you wouldn't do this, at least not for this purpose.

> Let's say I have a ball with X=0, and
>   a wall in X=10 and in a slow machine,
>   the first loop places the ball in X=7
>   and in a second loop, it places the
>   ball in X=14. It would just crash the
>   game!

Threading the two wouldn't solve this, unless you could guarantee that every single computer you used would always be fast enough to check X=1, X=2, X=3... X=10. You can't make this guarantee. And even if you could, it's rare to use integer numbers for positions. Can you iteratively check X=0.0000001, X=0.0000002, X=0.0000003 ... X=0.9999999, X=10.00000 ? Nope.

> How do you guys, experienced game developers work around this?

We typically still have one loop. input, update, render, repeat. Collision problems as you mention are solved by using a collision detection method that calculates the area that the object would pass through, eg. resolving for X=[0 to 17]. On a really slow machine it might be X=[0-50] and on a fast machine it might be X=[0-5] followed by X=[5-10], but each will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experience in game design and AI I would say to have a logical loop and a display loop (much like XNA sets up). The logical loop (Update method in XNA) will basically handle updating positions and what not, while the display loop (Draw method in XNA) will draw everything to the screen. As for collision detection, I would personally localize that to your ball. When it moves have it look for collision and react appropriately.

Threading is another topic, but in my opinion I would say not to seperate the update and draw. It just seems intrinsically wrong to me to potentially have 2 draws for 1 update or vice versa. Why draw if nothing has updated... or why update multiple times before showing the user what is happening.

Just my opinions, hope I'm not way off base.

Answer (score 0):

If logic updates are usually cheap, and rendering is occasionally expensive, the easiest thing to do is decide to have N logic updates per second. N=60 is common -- but you should just pick the smallest value that lets the game work well, pick a value and tweak the game until it works at that rate, or (more likely) some combination of the two.

At runtime, keep track of time actually elapsed, keep track of how much time has logically elapsed (in terms of updates performed), and when there's more than 1.0/N seconds of discrepancy (because the rendering is taking too long) perform extra updates to catch up. This is better than than trying perform an arbitrary period of time's-worth of updates in one go, because it's more predictable. (Should the reader disagree, they are welcome to find this out the hard way.)

The disadvantage of this system is that if the rendering becomes particularly time-consuming, and the logic has to perform too many updates because of this, the two can get a bit out of sync, and the logic will never catch up. If you're targetting a fixed system, this just indicates that you're trying to do to much, and you'll have to somehow do less, or (if this situation is likely to be rare) just dump the whole idea and do a 1:1 render:update. If you're targetting something variable like a Windows PC, you'll just have to clamp the number of catch-up logic updates, and hope that this will let things get back in line.

(If the logic is more expensive, this approach isn't appropriate; I've never worked on a game where this was a problem, though.)